# Python - How would you make the variables in this block global?

Tags: python, random, global-variables, global

[Python] I need to make the first 3 variables (attack, hitpoints, money) global but i dont know how because they are random (random.randint). Could someone tell me what the code should be? Thanks!

Edit: My error is something like "local variable 'money' referenced before assignment" later in the script.

Heres a link to the full script: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55052881/fightprogram.txt

Sorry if it's really sloppy, i just started learning python a week ago.

```
while roll == 1:

    attack = random.randint(1, 100)
    hitpoints = random.randint(1, 500)   
    money = random.randint(1, 1000)

    attackstr = str(attack)              
    hitpointsstr = str(hitpoints)
    moneystr = str(money)

    print()
    print('Your attack level is ' + attackstr + '.')
    print('You have ' + hitpointsstr + ' hitpoints.')
    print('Your have ' + moneystr + ' coins.')

    print()
    print('Type 1 to reroll.')
    print('Type 2 to proceed.')
    reroll = input()
    reroll = int(reroll)
    if reroll == 2:
        break
```

Comment: Could you please clarify? What does being assigned values from `random.randint` have anything to do with the variables being global? Also, is this in the main body of the script or inside a function? (in the first case, they're global, already...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what it means for a variable to be global.  I strongly suggest reading through Python's documentation on [scopes and namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), but I will do my best to summarize in a way that is relevant to your problem.

A "global variable" is a variable that is in the global namespace.  There is a separate global namespace for each module.  Besides modules, classes and functions are the only things that will create new scopes.  Any new variables you create will be placed in the innermost scope.

There is a [global keyword](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), which can be used to reference global variables, but this is only necessary when you are assigning to a global variable, for example:

```
x = 5
def foo():
    x = 10
def bar():
    global x
    x = 20

>>> x      # global variable x
5
>>> foo()  # foo creates a new x in the local scope
>>> x      # global x is unchanged
5
>>> bar()  # bar uses global keyword to reference the global x
>>> x      # global x is now 20
20
```

In your isolated code example, `attack`, `hitpoints`, and `money` are already global variables because they are not in any other scope, and they will be modified in each run of the loop.  If your code is actually in a class or a function, then adding the line `global attack, hitpoints, money` to the top of that scope will result in these variables being set in the global namespace for your module.

Comment: ohh, i think im starting to get it. later in the program i use the variable 'money' but its in a def block. would it work if i remove the def block and just type it each time?

Comment: THANK YOU! in all my def blocks i added global attack, hitpoints, money. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for days!

Answer (score 2):

I assume the code you posted is inside a function? If yes, you should *return* the values instead of using globals: `return attack, hitpoints, money` returns a tuple with those three values.

Otherwise, you can *write* to a variable in the global scope by defining it inside the function using the `global` statement:

```
global attack, hitpoints, money
```

Reading works without `global` by the way and so does modifying a mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize them with some initial value somewhere that has global scope.

Comment: Won't make a difference. In Python, `while` doesn't introduce a new scope.

Comment: Fixed? (more characters so SO will let me post this)

Comment: Still waiting for a clarification from Madison, because if that's all the code, the variables are global already :D

Comment: No, its not fixed yet. do you want the code from the whole program?

Comment: its a bit long, should i just put it in a comment?

Comment: its messed up if i post it in the question part and its too long to post in a comment. so im not sure how i can get it on here :/

Comment: Nevermind, heres a link to the full program: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55052881/fightprogram.txt

Comment: What happens if you put `attack = 0; hitpoints = 0; money = 0` at the top of your code?

Comment: no difference. i believe in my def gamble(): statement, when it searches for 'money' its looking for a local variable?... idk. it says local variable 'money' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Btw, you don't need `attackstr = str(attack)`

Python has built in string expansion, like this: `print('Your attack level is %s.' % attack)`